# What is a good way to sort a list by frequency?

Tags: python

This is kind of a weird question but here goes anyway.

I am writing a program in python that will allow a user to play the card game Go Fish vs a computer AI. If you don't know the rules to go fish here is a link to a page that describes them.
http://www.classicgamesandpuzzles.com/Go-Fish.html

I'm working on the part of the program that has the computer play its turn. On their turn the CPU will have to ask for a rank (ex. 1, 2, 3... ...Q, K, A) based on what is in their hand. I want the computer to ask for the number or rank that they already have the most of in their hand. To do this I would like to have a list of the ranks in there hand in order of how many of each rank there are. So for example the hand `[9D, 6S, KD, 9H, 6D, QC, 9C]`, would cause the computer to create a list looking like this.
`[9, 6, K, Q]` 
This way I could first have the computer ask for the first item in the list, 9, then if they receive it and get another turn it would have them ask for the next most frequent which in this case is 6.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to order the list like this or is there another easier way of accomplishing the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
cards = ["9D", "6S", "KD", "9H", "6D", "QC", "9C"]
ranks,suites = zip(*cards)
print Counter(ranks).most_common(1)[0]
```

Comment: `Counter(ranks).most_common(1)[0]` is a bit neater.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  hehe thanks :P I only use 2.6 si I dont have the counter class :P